# Are there any Add on to help arrange or organise nodes automatically like in Houdini?

Tags: node-editor, add-on, compositing-nodes, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I was looking for a way to automatically arrange my nodes similar to  [how Houdini does it](https://youtu.be/nN5XGd8ZLz8?t=290) and found out about this add-on already in blender called [Node Arrange](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_arrange.html). It works pretty well for now since I currently use very few nodes but it still has some issues and looking at its [Github](https://github.com/JuhaW/NodeArrange), it hasn't been updated in 4 yrs. Do you know any other free alternatives to this add-on?

Here are some pics:
This  is what it looks like arranging them manually
[image: Manual]

This is what it looks like after using the node arrange addon
[image: Node Arrange Addon]

This is what it looks like using the align node addon mentioned in the comments(I hit shift+E on the group input node and selected the dependecies to the right)
[image: Align Node Addon]

Comment: Can you explain that functions you expect from this add-on, for people who have never used Houdini?

Comment: [Houdini Node Layout Tools](https://youtu.be/nN5XGd8ZLz8?t=290)

Answer (score 1):

There are several that do part of the job automatically, but I don't know of any that would do it all at once..  Node Wrangler, the built-in add-on, has a few features to help, of course.  Another one is [Align Nodes](https://github.com/3DSinghVFX/align_nodes) also on GitHub. It provides a tool for moving dependent nodes relative to each other.